# Finding @throws exceptions: What exceptions does PHPDoc expect from this method?

Tags: php, datetime, exception, phpdoc

I have this class method, and my IDE (PHPStorm) is notifying me that it is missing [@throws tags in the PHPDoc](http://docs.phpdoc.org/references/phpdoc/tags/throws.html):

```
/**
 * Return Time Frame for request to API
 *
 * @since 2.4.7
 *
 * Default time_frame is two dates, start of current week, and four weeks from now.
 *
 * @return array or start and end dates as required for MBO API
 */
public function time_frame(){
    $start_time = new \Datetime( date_i18n('Y-m-d', current_time( 'timestamp' )) );
    $end_time = new \Datetime( date_i18n('Y-m-d', current_time( 'timestamp' )) );
    $di = new \DateInterval('P4W');
    $end_time->add($di);

    return array('StartDateTime'=> $start_time->format('Y-m-d'), 'EndDateTime'=> $end_time->format('Y-m-d'));
}
```

I'm though maybe the `exceptions` that would be thrown by this function are for `Datetime` and `DateInterval`: `DateTime::__construct()`, `DateInterval::__construct()`.

Adding

```
* @throws DateTime::__construct()
* @throws DateInterval::__construct()
```

Isn't satisfying the validator. Any suggestions?

Comment: What php version did you use?

Comment: Usually, the throws tag is used to indicate what exception the method will be throwing, if any. Not what the classes it uses would be throwing

Comment: @Charis php7.1, or possibly point 2.

Answer (score 2):

Tried adding `@throws \Exception` on the docs. According to \DateTime class constructor and DateInterval constructor, each class could throws \Exception if some parameter not correctly declared. Timezone for DateTime and interval_spec on DateInterval

reference: [DatetTime::__construct reference](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php)

Comment: Thanks, Charis. I think I had tried `@throws Exception` without the namespace escape and had even made it to the page you referenced. It just seemed silly to note that if it throws something it will be an "exception" because that's the only thing you can throw, isn't it?

Comment: Well. Some linter wont accept it if the type wont match though. Some type checking I've encounter need explicitly declare the exact exception class it throws. Like runtimeexception or invalidargumentexception.

Comment: There can be different kinds of exceptions being thrown, not just the base `\Exception` class.  @Charis' examples of `\RuntimeException` and `\InvalidArgumentException` are children of `\Exception`.  Sometimes you want to throw a specific exception to better denote what went wrong, rather than just the plain `\Exception`.  Sometimes, as the caller, you have code to handle certain exceptions, but not others. Your method calls out to several Date methods, which are known to throw certain exceptions. Since the API reader reads your docs, not the method body, `@throws` is how you communicate that.